# Growable 8-bit byte buffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, bytebuffer

I am looking for a type that would allow me to manipulate growable byte buffers in JavaScript; essentially, an equivalent to the Python `bytearray` type. My criteria for a solution is that the buffer should be:

- **Growable**: the buffer *must* support resizing; for this reason `ArrayBuffer`/`Uint8Array` (on their own, at least) will not do.
- **Efficient**: I should have a reasonable expectation that using the buffer does not generate unreasonable amounts of overhead even in (relatively) naïve engines; for this reason, an `Array` of numbers will not do.
- **Portable**: this needs to run in a browser, so nothing specific to node.js; though an ideal solution would only rely directly on APIs specified in ECMA and WHATWG standards.

Is there a 8-bit byte buffer type that fulfils these criteria?

Comment: I don't see why an Array wouldn't do. Sure TypedArrays are *more* efficient, but that's precisely because they have a fixed size. Still Arrays are reasonably efficient. If you face a perf issue using Arrays, then maybe show what you are doing so we can help you improve it.

Comment: TypedArrays are more efficient mainly because they don’t have to account for sparse and heterogeneously-typed arrays; the fixed size is less important. A straightforward Array implementation would store elements as pointers or NaN-tagged floats; I’ve read V8 stores arrays of ‘small integers’ in a more efficient manner than that, but I’d rather not rely on opportunistic optimisations like this.

Comment: Still are you facing an actual issue with Arrays? There is no such thing as what you ask for. Reassigning a new ArrayBuffer will probably be slower than working on an Array all along. And IIRC the most perf boost is indeed because ArrayBuffers are sequentially stored in memory.

Comment: Yes, the actual issue is that it’s inefficient. If you believe no such thing exists, you can write it as an answer – though I guess a summary of solutions that compromise on the criteria would help too.

Comment: How is it inefficient? Show something where there is a clear inefficiency using Arrays so we can see how an other solution would be beneficial or not. From what you give, Arrays fullfill all of that. Arrays are growable, with Arrays you can *"have a reasonable expectation that using the buffer does not generate unreasonable amounts of overhead"*, and it's *portable*.

Comment: (Also, sequential storage is not inherently incompatible with growability: look at `std::vector` in C++.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [ResizableArrayBuffer](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-resizablearraybuffer) specification under development. As of this writing, it is at stage 2, so it has no major implementations. For now, `Array`s will have to do.